# Why would the Ressurectinator cause phantom pain in the people it brings back?

Tags: science-based

The Ressurectinator is a handy machine than can bring back people from death. Unlike the virgin Lord of Light, the chad  Ressurectinator does that without human sacrifice and/or permanent scars. You only need the person's brainscan. Everyone has one, it's constantly updated and nothing can destroy it.

There is one weakness to the machine, however. **The person, it brings back, would feel the pain they felt when dying, WITHOUT the dopamine/adrenaline that coursed through their body.** This is weird, since the machine brings back demi-humans and dragons as well, both of whom have much stronger senses, and thus, a stronger sense of pain. It doesn't helps that most of them sustain horrible injuries before dying (broken wings, throat sliced up to the chin, 3rd degree burns).

The machine is owned by the good guys and isn't designed to make a profit. Logically, phantom pain would be used as a deterrent, so the good guys finish the war with declaring bankruptcy. However, dying IS painful and HORRIFYING. The effects of the Ressurectinator are guaranteed to increase the number of soldiers with PTSD, which is even worse than respawn abuse.

**So, why would the machine do this?**

Anything I didn't touch upon about the machine or the good guys (religion, morality, evil professor) cannot be used in the answer.

Comment: I think this is a perfect place for handwaving it in your story.  You kinda have a Ship of Theseus problem going on here that's best just avoided.

Comment: Does the machine require (what's left of) the body, or a scan of the person, or does it recreate them entirely from scratch?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Slight potential loophole -- the last feeling needn't be the horrific thing that causes death. Depending on the technology and tactics in your universe, you have a good chance of pulling fatally wounded soldiers out of combat and administering peaceful euthanasia.

Answer (score 6):

**The machine doesn't cause it, the brain does**

Phantom pain is the sensation of a lost limb. It's a bit weird, given that there's no limb to give the pain and no nerves, so there's only one explanation - its psychosomatic. The pain is in the mind, it's some part of the brain which hasn't acknowledged the missing arm. And, as a plus, it's not well understood. (Why is that a plus? It means we don't have to use excessive handwavium because we're not contradicting established fact.)

When a person dies, there body gives out, and then the electric synapses it the brain does. (Not it all case, but most. This won't happen if the entire head goes at once.) That means that the brain has acknowledged, on some level, that the body has been destroyed. Thus, when the body is resurrected, there's still a part of the brain that 'remembers' the destroyed body, and attempts to overlay it onto the new body when the person uses it. For instance, if you suffered a shot to the heart and died from it, whenever a message involving the heart is sent to the brain, some subconscious part of it is triggered, says 'that's funny, we don't have a heart because it got shot', and then the message of 'the heart got shot' gets sent to person. It makes sense - there's no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: I like this answer, but there's a bit of a problem in that, our mind is wholly in our brain.  The machine must be able to implant memories, else a destroyed brain would forget things.  So why does it implant the memories that cause phantom pain?  Would you want to remember how it felt to get shot in the heart?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have a choice. It could be that the machine isn't complex enough to be able to pick and choose memories - it's an all-or-none type of deal.

Comment: @Ryan_L Clearly it's because Tahiti didn't work so well!

Answer (score 5):

## The Cost of Verisimilitude when Accounting for Ineffable Variables

#### You aren't You

The problem with transporter technology is that the person who appears at the destination is not the person who stepped into the transporter at the origin: they are a duplicate, and the original is gone forever.

The same problem would ostensibly exist with the Ressurectinator: it merely inserts the brainscan of the patient into a new body.  The person who died isn't the same person who came back, just an exact duplicate.

But that begs the question: what has been lost in this process?  The science of the Ressurectinator can account for all physical variables, down to subatomic particles, so the only difference must lie in something outside of physical variables.  Something ineffable; scientists could just refer to this as "the soul" for quick reference.

#### Why aren't You Yourself?

Keeping the brain scans updated is easy: the Ressurectinator has a read-only quantum-entangled pattern of the patient's mind which is updated in real-time as they go about their day.  One visit to the Ressurectinator is all it takes to get the process started.

Early experiments involved resurrecting someone using a 1-minute "tail" of their realtime scan, allowing them to be brought back without the traumatic memory of death itself.  But this raised ethical concerns: if someone is being resurrected with part of their memories missing, then are they *truly* themselves?  Those performing the resurrection have essentially edited out an inconvenient memory from their patient, and brought back a mere duplicate.  The person who originally stepped into the Ressurectinator to get their brain scanned is dead forever.

### If it Stings, that means It's Working

The solution was to use the *final* brain scan; the last moment when the scan stopped updating and became static.  That is the *truest* possible copy.  The variable has stopped varying, and become a constant.

When this scan is used, the patient is resurrected with all of their memories intact, including those of dying.  The downside is that the pain they felt at that moment is now persistent.

Some scientists might believe this is the equivalent of the Soul itself being scarred by the experience, and evidence that using the "true" final scan allows the Soul itself to be brought back.  This is not merely a duplicate, but undeniably the same person who died.

Other scientists might believe that this is just a side effect of using the brain scan after it has stopped updating--the sensations experienced at the time of death are now "hard coded" into the scan itself.  The unfortunate fact is that no one knows for certain.

But regardless, there is agreement on one fact: a person resurrected with these phantom pains is the truest possible resurrection.  Anything else is just a copy.

Answer (score 1):

**Your new body is an approximation of your old body.**

You are more than just a brain scan, your mind only works when integrated into YOUR body.

If you throw a dead body into the machine it can perfectly revive all the parts that are still in tact, but the missing and damaged bits are a simulation of what that part should look like.  The machine guesses what cellular structures should be there, but things tend to come out slightly extruded or misaligned.  This approximation is good enough for muscles, bones, and other tissues so you do not appear scared, but the exact course your nerves take through your body are much more precise and unpredictable; so, they tend to get pinched or malformed in recreation process.

Answer (score 1):

**Soul.**

That could case quite the uproar in the scientific community. You have empirical proof that with the *same* mind using the *same* body it does't work the *same*.

The process is repeatable and can be validated by technicians in other facilities.

The model of what constitutes a human is thus insufficient and must be further developed. That's a Pandora's box with plenty plot bunnies to write a fun story.